# Create a legend for qplot graph with stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a file which contains a data frame. Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Ztudba6S3qbkUtR09QUFBZbWM/view?usp=sharing) to the file

```
tmp <- read.csv("tmp.csv")
m <- qplot(UW_rank, number_correction, data = tmp, 
       alpha = I(1/3), 
       geom = c("point"),
       xlab = "Underwriter rank",
       ylab = "Number of SEC letters",
       main = "Number of SEC Letters and UW Rank",
      ) 
m <- m + stat_summary(aes(colour = "mean"), fun.y = mean, 
                  geom = "line",
                  color = "red",
                  size = 1.1)
```

As a result I have the following picture
[image]

I was to add a legend to this graph which will explain that red line is the mean. How can I do that. I have tried **scale_fill_manual**  and **geom_text** but was not able to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Don't use `stat_summary`; calculate the means separately in another data frame, and then add it in its own layer with `geom_line`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@joran's approach of pre-summarizing the data will work fine (and if you have a large data set, it will be faster than `stat_summary`), but you can also do it directly by mapping a color aesthetic to "mean" in `stat_summary` and then adding some additional code to get the colors and labels you want. I've used the built-in `mtcars` data set as an example:

```
p1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl,mpg)) + 
        geom_point() 

p1 +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(cyl, mpg, colour="mean")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("mean"="blue")) +  # Set line color to blue
  labs(colour="")  # Get rid of the redundant legend title
```

[image]